# Determine which of the following relation is a function?

Tags: functions, relations

Given two set $ A = \{0, 2, 4, 6\}$ and $B = \{1, 3, 5, 7\}$, determine which of the following relation is a function?

$(a) \{(6, 3), (2, 1), (0, 3), (4, 5)\}$,

$(b) \{(2, 3), (4, 7), (0, 1), (6, 5)\}$,

$(c) \{(2, 1), (4, 5), (6, 3)\}$,

$(d) \{(6, 1), (0, 3), (4, 1), (0, 7), (2, 5)\}$.

---

My attempt :

"So far I know that for an equation to be functional, any x value cannot be repeated. You cannot have two x's. Y can repeat however much it wants to but despite that not being able to determine which are functional.

Comment: Option (a) and (b) both are true, since a function has exactly one output of every element of domain of function.

Comment: Which of the four relations do you think are functions?  Note that only one of these relations has a repeated $x$-value.

Comment: So what is your take on this question? How would you solve it? Please provide some of your own solution and where you get stuck, in order for us to be better able to help you.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I think a, b and d are functional.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I understood for why a and b, isn't d functional? I think it is not because 0 are repeated.

Comment: You are correct that (d) is not a function for the reason you stated.  You should include your ideas on how to solve the problem in the question itself rather than the comments, where they may be overlooked.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you guys!! Finally understood what it means

Comment: @Sakar What are your thoughts on (c)?

Comment: In common sense, (c) should be a function, just like $f(x)={1\over x}$ is commonly considered a function on $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think that as it has no 0, it cannot be functional.

Comment: Ah, but the definition of a function only prohibits repeated "x"-values.  Any element in the domain must map to *at most* one element in the co-domain.

Comment: Function from A to B?

Answer (score 1):

**A relation** is a set of ordered pairs, which maps from one set, called the domain, to another set, called the co-domain.    Here $A$ is the domain, and $B$ is the co-domain.   All the sets given in the OP are indeed relations of $A\to B$; but are they functions?

**A function** is a relation where any element of the domain is mapped to *at most* one element in the co-domain.   That is: no two distinct pairs of the relation will share the same left-member (or "x"-value; or rather "A"-value in this case).

( PS: "at most one" means either *one* or *none*, but *never* two or more. )

That is *it*!   That's the only property you have to test.   There is *no* restriction on sharing the right members ("y"-values; or "B" values here).

Answer (score 0):

A function is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to exactly one output.

So, according definition of function, given relations with domain $A = \{0, 2, 4, 6\}$,

$(a) \{(6, 3), (2, 1), (0, 3), (4, 5)\} = \{ (0, 3),(2, 1), (4, 5),(6, 3)\}$ is function , since it defines for every element of function $(i.e.\{0, 2, 4, 6\})$ and has exactly one output for each element.

$(b) \{(2, 3), (4, 7), (0, 1), (6, 5)\} = \{(0, 1),(2, 3), (4, 7), (6, 5)\}$ is function , since it defines for every element of function $(i.e.\{0, 2, 4, 6\})$ and has exactly one output for each element.

$(c) \{(2, 1), (4, 5), (6, 3)\}$ is not a function, since it defines on element $0$ of element of function $(i.e.\{0, 2, 4, 6\})$.

$(d) \{(6, 1), (0, 3), (4, 1), (0, 7), (2, 5)\} = \{(0, 3),(0, 7),(2, 5),(4, 1),(6, 1) \}$ is not a function, since it not has exactly one output of element of function $(i.e.\{0, 2, 4, 6\})$. Element $0$ have two output $3$ and $7$.

Reference@[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thank you and yes I now understand what functions are